# jQuery setting dynamic options selected by equal dynamic value invalid after show/hide

Tags: jquery, select

I made a edit panel which will show up when user click a button.

I use jQuery data Table, there is a button at begin of row. when button is clicked, panel will show up. In click function I set select option being selected if value equal to row data. I try two ways to do this.

```
 $("#editCountry option[value='" + data.Country + "'").attr("Selected", true);

 $("#editBranch option").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == data.BranchID) {
                $(this).attr("Selected", true);
            } else {
                $(this).attr("Selected", false);
            }
        })
```

it works, however when the value of other row is different, for example, 
row a country == US, 
row b country == DEU,

then when I click row b then click row a again, the select will never change again. It will always stop at first row, I check the html code via develop panel, the collect one is selected, but just display the wrong option.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do like this

```
 $("#editCountry option[value='" + data.Country + "'").attr("Selected", true);
```

You can simply do this as follows

```
 $("#editCountry").val(data.Country);
```

Comment: Thanks. I change the way you provide, but when I click another row(same div show different value setting) which with different country value, then all select does not change anymore, very strange...